# ViewPager on setting current item >0 creating two instance of fragment

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have two Activities. Activity A and Activity B

Activity A - has a listview

Activity B - has a ViewPage with FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Whenever the user clicks on any item of the listview. I am starting the Activity B passing the index of the item clicked. In the Activity B am setting the adapter on viewpager and setting the currentItem to the index of the item clicked on Activity A.

Now the Problem is viewpager is first creating the fragment for the 0th item and after that its creating the index item. I don't want that extra item to be created. Any solution?

Portion of code:

```
ViewPager vp = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
ViewPagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), cursor);
vp.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
vp.setCurrentItem(index);

private class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        private Cursor cursor;

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager, Cursor cursor) {
            super(fragmentManager);
            this.cursor = cursor;
        }   

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int index) {
                return new Fragment(index);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return cursor.getCount();
        }

}
```

**Update:** I know ViewPage creates the left and right of the current fragment. But in my case if I setCurrentItem to 10 its creating 0th in addition to 9th and 11th. 0th item is getting created just after I call vp.setAdapter(pagerAdapter) and on the next line am setting the currentItem that's when it goes to index item. The question is not about any scrolling issue. The question is why it's creating the 0th and way to solve it.

Comment: check your index is proper or not

Comment: index is proper. If my index is 5 I see 5th item not 0th. Problem is its creating the instance of both fragments 0th and 5th.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to over come this, I have an alternative way. How many fragments do you have?

Comment: try to pass index is constructor and in getItem() return the fragment on index position

Comment: No of items in cursor is not fixed.

Comment: is it fixed that no given by activity A is there on Activity B?

Comment: yes, same db query is used on both screens.

Comment: you are creating some mistake in indexing please provide your fragment creation code also

Answer (score 1):

I guess behavior you want is not possible due to 
`ViewPager` implementation. `ViewPager` depends on "scrolling" behavior and knowledge about current neighbors and cache those veiws. So `setCurrentItem` inside :

```
 setCurrentItemInternal(item, !mFirstLayout, false);
```

And inside this method:

```
mCurItem = item;
if (dispatchSelected) {
    dispatchOnPageSelected(item);
}
requestLayout();
```

And finally in onLayout :

```
scrollToItem(mCurItem, false, 0, false);
```

`ViewPager` will create neighbors of current page (total 3 fragments). You can reduce it to only creation of 2 fragments:

```
mViewPager.setCurrentItem(id, false); //disable smooth scroll
```

Also change your fragment like so :

```
private static final String ARG_INDEX = "itemPosition";
private int mPageIndex;

public static BlankFragment newInstance(int index) {
    BlankFragment fragment = new BlankFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ARG_INDEX, index);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mPageIndex = getArguments().getInt(ARG_INDEX);
    }
}
```

And use like here :

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return BlankFragment.newInstance(position);
}
```

You can't depend on fragment constuctor to pass parameters to fragment as it can be recreated.

Comment: ViewPage creates the left and right of the current fragment. But in my case if I setCurrentItem to 10 its creating 0th in addition to 9th and 11th. The question is not about any scrolling issue. The question is why it's creating the 0th and way to solve it.

Comment: Strange, I've created test project and only neighbors of current item were created. I think i know what is your problem

Comment: I am creating the fragment same way. Above is just a sample code. In your sample just add a log for index in the on create of your fragment or in the setUserHintVisible

Comment: Then it's really strange - i haven't such issue on my environment. I've tracked all events, added log to `ViewPagerAdapter::instantiateItem` to track request for item creation, to fragment's `onCreate` where index extracted from args. but can't reproduce.

Comment: 0th item is getting created just after I call vp.setAdapter(pagerAdapter) and on the next line am setting the currentItem that's when it goes to index item

Comment: what version of `support-v4` library are you using?

Comment: am using version 23.4.0

Comment: checked with your version - can't reproduce too.

Comment: try adding a log in the newItem method of your adapter

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122898/discussion-between-gaurav-singla-and-j2ko).

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding a check in my adapter and returning a dummy fragment.

Sample Code:

```
private class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        private int currentItemIndex,count;
        private boolean currentItemCreated;

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager, int currentItemIndex,int count) {
            super(fragmentManager);
        this.count= count;
            this.currentItemIndex = currentItemIndex;
        }


        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int index) {
            if (index == currentItemIndex) {
                currentItemCreated = true;
            }
            if (currentItemCreated) {

                return new YourFragment();
            } else {
                return new Fragment();
            }
        }


        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return count;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

try like this

```
  private class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        private Cursor cursor;
        private int index;

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager, Cursor cursor,int indext) {
            super(fragmentManager);
            this.cursor = cursor;

            this.index=indext;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int index) {
            //method to find fragment at that index
            return fragment();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return cursor.getCount();
        }

    }
}
```